# when does C creates variables?

Tags: c, debugging, variables

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and Qt Creator 2.4.1. It builds my C code by default `GCC`.

I am debugging my program (`Qt Creator (uses GDB)`) and can already see lots of variables that would be called/created in the later steps of the program. Is it normal to see all variables in the beginning of the program? In another word, do I see the variables in the early stage of the program because of the debug option (`-g`)? For example, I 'step into' the code and stops in the first step which is `int main()` [image: a busy cat]

`char[1000] mesg;` is executed on the 129th line however, I can see it and its memory address already. or `int tem_hopt_dist=0;` is on the line 230 but I already see its value as '3'.

Comment: Many times, statically defined variables get compiled into the data "section" of a program, thus if you are in scope of that routine / function, then it may become visible at that point.  Anything that is statically in the Data section may be allocated at entry to that routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The debugger does not understand all the scoping semantics of the language, and displays data as if all the variables were initialized in their final memory locations even when they're out of scope.

Some debuggers are better than others. This is a frequent source of irritation, for example if you are in the habit of having separate index variables all called `i`, and the debugger won't differentiate between them.

Answer (score 4):

Variables with "static duration" (not the same thing as the `static` keyword, although variables declared `static` generally do have static duration) are, in the execution model, "created" by the time `main` is called.  Variables with "automatic duration" ("on the stack", as many people call them) are created by the time their scope is entered.  Variables allocated via `malloc` last until explicitly `free`d (or the space is reduced via `realloc`, etc).

The key take-away above is not "are created *at* this point" but rather "*by* this point".  The compiler is free to do it earlier, if that's more efficient.  For block-scope, automatic-duration variables, it's generally cheapest to lump them all into one big entry-point stack allocation, which the compiler can do with a single "subtract" instruction ("subtract constant from stack pointer") on most typical modern machines.  Releasing the space is either entirely free ("return from function" does it) or again takes just one instruction ("add constant to stack pointer").

C99's Variable Length Arrays ("VLAs") complicate this a bit.  A VLA often has to be allocated each time its enclosing block is entered, and released each time the block is exited.  Again, this is generally fairly cheap (one subtract from stack pointer to create the VLA, and one add to destroy it), but obviously two instructions per block is more expensive than zero instructions per block.  This also interferes slightly with some compile-time optimizations.

If you ever use the non-standard `alloca` function, this also is generally implemented by subtraction from the stack pointer, and it may not "play well" with VLAs, since that kind of subtraction tends to assume that the compiler has done its own "subtract from stack pointer" exactly once, just before the function itself got started.